# Delphi DX Seattle FMX TListView HeaderItem - Hide white Shadow text on non white background

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey

I have noticed that when you change the ListView header background color there is a weird white text like shadow

[image]

does anyone know how to get rid of the white shadow?

Steps to reproduce

Create a FMX project, put a list view on it and align it to client
right click on the listview and choose edit custom style
In the lv1style1: TFmxObject find the header structure
[image]

select the source link property and move the default selected area to some other color
[image]

populate the list view on form create - with the code like this

```
var lvitem : TListViewItem;
begin
  lvitem := lv1.Items.Add;
  lvitem.Text := 'Header';
  lvitem.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Header;
  lvitem.Detail := '';


  lvitem := lv1.Items.Add;
  lvitem.Text := 'none';
  lvitem.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.None;

  lvitem := lv1.Items.Add;
  lvitem.Text := 'footer';
  lvitem.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Footer;
```

if you have any questions please comment below
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a TextLabel.TextShadowColor setting 
On the List view OnUpdateObjects
Added the following code

```
procedure TForm1.lv1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  TextLabel: TListItemText;
begin
  if AItem.Purpose in [TListItemPurpose.Header, TListItemPurpose.Footer] then begin
    TextLabel := AItem.Objects.TextObject;
    TextLabel.TextShadowColor := TalphaColorRec.Null;
  end;
end;
```

[image: No Shadow]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at ListView style internals, one may notice, that there is 'headetext' color object. Deducing, that some ListView code should load the color object to reflect the current styling, we may do the search in FMX pas files, and find the following styling code:

```
  // Item Colors
```

FStyleResources.DefaultTextColor := GetColorFromStyle('foreground', claBlack);
  FStyleResources.DefaultTextSelectedColor := GetColorFromStyle('selectiontext', claBlack);
  FStyleResources.DetailTextColor := GetColorFromStyle('detailtext', claBlack);
  FStyleResources.HeaderTextColor := GetColorFromStyle('headertext', claWhite);
  FStyleResources.HeaderTextShadowColor := GetColorFromStyle('headertextshadow', claWhite);

So, there **IS** an option to control the text shadow color through styles, the style portion controlling it is just not there.
Well, adding 'headertextshadow' TColorObject into each corresponding ListView style, and setting its color to Null, would solve your case without any code involved.